# install matlab 2013a with error

Tags: installation, java, 32-bit, matlab

I tried to install Matlab2013a in my laptop (Ubuntu system). I download a ISO file (very big) and followed their instruction: mount it and run "install". But it returns me an error:

`Cannot locate Java Runtime Enviroment (JRE). The directory ~/Matlab/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre does not exist.`

In the folder `~/Matlab/sys/java/jre/`, what I have is "glnxa64". Does that mean that I can't install this version of Matlab in my 32bit laptop? This java comes from Matlab. How should I get it work?

Comment: There is no 32-bit version of Matlab 2013a for UNIX, try some older versions. I'm using 2012b version with no problems on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Hello MATLAB supports **only 64bits version** so you must a ubuntu 64 bits see this link of mathworks:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html?sec=linux

Comment: Yes, that's the case. I can't use such a new version of Matlab, which doesn't support 32-bit. Thanks!